# PHPMyadmin no muestra los ultimos registros de la tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla `logs` que tiene 700,000 registros. Cuando voy al apartado "Browse" en phpmyadmin para ver los registros de la tabla, doy click en el símbolo ">>" para ir a la "ultima pagina", básicamente para ir al final de la tabla y ver los registros mas recientes.

Phpmyadmin no muestra los últimos registros, siempre se queda en registros de hace un mes y me dice que no hay nada mas después del ultimo registro que me muestra, pero si manualmente hago un `SELECT * FROM logs WHERE ID > 785000;`, la consulta si me muestra los últimos registros.

La tabla estuvo trabajando bien hasta hace semana. 
La tabla maneja su campo ID Auto incremental, por lo tanto los registros mas nuevos si tienen los números mas grandes.

Alguna idea de que este pasando o como puedo resolver esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM logs
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Te ordenará los registros de forma descendente

Comment: Es cierto, sin embargo estoy buscando una manera de hacer que phpmyadmin "trabaje correctamente", gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Para una tabla que tiene la cantidad de registros que tu indicas, te recomiendo que revises si la misma tiene índices, esto ayudará a que PhpMyAdmin puede optimizar la búsqueda de registros: https://www.siteground.es/kb/optimizacion-mysql-usando-indexes/

Incluso, si el problema es con Phpmyadmin, te sugiero usar un cliente de escritorio para mysql como heidiSQL o navicat

Comment: Señor santiago muchas gracias, en efecto era el indice, el campo ID estaba como llave primaria, basto agregar la propiedad de indice para solucionar el asunto. Gracias.